# Kendu UI Tabsbstrip views can't load jquery validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui, jquery-validate, kendo-tabstrip

I have an issue when using Kendo UI's Tabstrip. I have two tabs in the tabstrip, and I want to use clientside jquery validation in the First of the views in the tabstrip.

Google Chrome: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkxAd.png]

I have a View where I load the tabstrip, and here I can render the script for validation.

View with tabstrip: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pguI.png]

In the tab where I want to do the validation in, I can't render the script.

View with validation: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6riW.png]

Even though the script is loaded in the view with the tabstrip in, I can't get the clientside validation to work in the first tab, and can't render the validation script in the view with the validation.

Anyone have a suggestion to fix this issue?

I have a little side question. How do I return from the controller, and in to the tab view if the validation fails serverside?

Now I have:

Controller: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRDhs.png]

Where I return a PartialView, but it fills the whole view instead of only returning to the view in the tab.

Comment: Please start by posting the actual code rather than pictures or screenshots of code.  It should be obvious why that practice is frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the problem is that events for the partial are lost when they are loaded via AJAX. What we do (using kendo validation) is add an event to the tab that handles content load:

```
.Events(ev =>
 {
     ev.ContentLoad("onContentLoad")
 })
```

then in the script reload the validation:

```
function onContentLoaded() {
   $("form").kendoValidator();
};
```

There is another technique for jquery validation that involves code like this:

```
function onContentLoaded() {
   // clear validation attributes
   $("form").removeData("validator");
   $("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
   // add validation attributes back
   $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
};
```

Regarding your 2nd question, if validation fails, you return your partial view which should have the validation attributes already set.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with removing the @section Scripts {}

Used only the @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")